# MP4 Video won't load on web site

Tags: html, video, embed, mp4

I have been trying all different ways to embed an .mp4 video onto a website that I am working on.  Here is the link to it...

http://mcmach.com/MCMachine/

I have tested locally and the video does load fine, but not when I pull up the live version on the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the video exist on the server in the correct directory?

Answer (score 1):

Your video doesn't exist.  You are trying to link to this URL:

http://mcmach.com/MCMachine/videos/MC_Machine_HP.mp4

Your server is giving you a 404.  Either fix the name, or upload the missing video.  Note that you can easily find this kind of problem yourself by looking in your browser tools' network tab.

Comment: Have checked and the video does exist in the location that I thought it did...How could I be naming this file wrong?

Comment: @Dan, The video does not exist at that URL.  If you believe that it does, check the permissions on the file, to ensure that the web server can read it.  Also remember that most web servers are case-sensitive with file names.